# Are there cases where using the definition is easier than using the derivative to study the monotonic behaviour of a function?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, monotone-functions

This is more a curiosity,

Say I have a function $f \in C^{1}(A)$ where $A \subset \mathbb{R}$. What could be an instance of function where studying the monotonic behaviour using the definition is better than using the derivative? Any example which is not trivial would be appreciated.

Comment: to clarify, definition of what?

Comment: I thought it was clear... "monotonic". Strictly increasing/decreasing.

Comment: So basically anything where you can compute the values more easily than computing an explicit expression for the derivative...?

Comment: I don't think it is "values" since, for example you need to prove that for all $x < y$ you have $f(x) < f(y)$.

Comment: So basically I'm looking for an expression where studying the difference $f(x) - f(y)$ is more convenient than computing the derivative.

Answer (score 1):

I think in the case when you have composition of incrasing functions or something similar. For example $$f(x) = e^{\arctan e^{x^{7677677}}}$$

Comment: The study of the sign in that specific case wouldn't be that hard, I guess.